# What happen after Enel finished his business in moon?

Tags: one-piece

At the end of [Enel's Great Space Operations](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Enel%27s_Great_Space_Operations), he seems to be satisfied with how things goes on the moon.

> Looking around, Enel sees endless followers, and an enormous amount of "vearth", and decides that the "Fairy Vearth" was everything that he had wanted.

But what happen after that? Did he goes back to earth?

Answer (score 2):

Enel becomes the ruler of the moon according the wikia
http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Enel

> Originally, Enel met a few more recent ones who came from the planet
>   below to avenge their fallen creator on Machine Island. First
>   Lieutenant Spacey was the first automaton that Enel encountered on the
>   moon. He survived his encounter with the Space Pirates who came there
>   to dig up the ancient city located on the moon. After meeting Enel, he
>   considered him his savior. After finding his true roots, Enel
>   established a new empire on the moon with the automata as his
>   followers.

He stays on the moon.