# Where is Enel going after fight with Luffy?

Tags: one-piece

Now Enel have the strong weapon. But when he face luffy, he lose. And then he go.
In my opinion i think enel going back to one piece story and then will be the man whose destroy a New World. 
According you, where is enel? When he back?

Comment: "Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."

Comment: @Bálint  This is should be closed as a duplicate not as opinion based.  Opinion based is "we can't answer that factually" when the truth is we already have the answer on this site in detail.

Comment: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6883/what-happen-after-enel-finished-his-business-in-moon

Comment: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6882/how-can-enel-reach-the-moon

Comment: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/21849/what-is-fairy-vearth

Answer (score 0):

Longing for the endless Vearth he went to the moon :3

Comment: seriously he go to the moon? wkwkwkkw
how he still alive?

Comment: Yeah he did  you should check out this wiki http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Enel's_Great_Space_Operations .. He didn't have to breath in the outer space it think.

Comment: This answer could use more detail... but is correct.